# How do I preseve an object type member inside an ASP.Net MVC view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

Here are my two classes:

```
class Company
{
   public int ID{ get; set; }
   public string CompanyName{ get; set; }
}

public class Division
{
   public int ID{ get; set; }
   public string DivisionName{ get; set; }
   public virtual Company Company { get; set; }
}
```

I have a strongly typed EDIT view for Division, with an `EditorFor` for DivisionName and a `HiddenFor` for ID.

The problem I have is when I hit save, the Controller action gets the Division object with an NULL for Company property. When the model is not valid, and the View is returned with that object, I can no longer extract the company name in the view using `@Model.Company.CompanyName`.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't include Company data in your view (as input fields), then nothing about Company will be posted back.

If Company is just for "display only", then re-populate it in your controller during the post before your model is returned in the view.

```
public ActionResult MyAction(Division model)
{
  // ...

  // Repopulate Company
  model.Company = new Company() { ... };

  return View(model);
}
```

Comment: I was hoping to avoid doing that.

Comment: The data has to come from somewhere :)

Comment: Try the post asynchronously then. If that's not an option, what's the reasoning behind not wanting to refill the Company object? If it's a performance concern then make sure you're doing as much client-side validation as possible so an invalid model on the server becomes a rare error condition.